# cant insert record with reference to another record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models: `platform` and `place` *(platform and place on platform)*

**platform**

```
{
  name: {
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    type: String,
    empty: false
  },
  description: {
    required: false,
    type: String,
    empty: true
  }
}
```

**place**

```
{
  name: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
    empty: false
  },
  platform: new Mongoose.Schema({
    type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: PlatformSchema
  })
}
```

The name of `platform` must be unique. First, I generate list of platforms. Then trying generate list of places on this platforms and receive error.

```
WriteError({
  "code": 11000,
  "index": 1,
  "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.places index: platform.ref.name_1 dup key: { : null }",
  "op": {
    "_id": "5b7ea477798f9c41f81c0234",
    "name": "top",
    "platform": {
      "_id":"5b7ea41b878b4a41abcfc952"
    }
  }
})
```

Receive it until unique index for "name" field exists in `platform` schema.

I try insert `place` many ways:

```
PlaceRecord.insertMany([
  {
    name: "top",
    platform: platformDocumentInstance
  }
])
```

or

```
PlaceRecord.insertMany([
  {
    name: "top",
    platform: platformDocumentInstance
  }
])
```

or

```
PlaceRecord.insertMany([
  {
    name: "top",
    platform: platformDocumentInstance
  }
])
```

But result is same one. Note first record of `place` success inserted, but next record of `place` throw the exception. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the document that you are inserting first has inserts null as platform.ref.name and when you insert second document your index platform.ref.name_1 fails because there is already a record with null.